# Multiple dynamic forms in one view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

In my project I have one view that populates dynamically, creating either a single or multiple forms on one screen / page. I have managed to dynamically give each form a unique id, however when there are multiple forms on one page, an array of all forms is returned when only one is submitted and I do not know how to identify the actual instance that is being submitted from the array.

Here is my View;

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model IEnumerable<Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "View question";
   ViewBag.Page = Model.First().PageNumber;
}
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
@foreach (var q in Model.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionRanking))
{
Html.BeginForm("ViewQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = @q.formNumber, role = "form" });
var qtype = q.QuestionTypeId;
<div>
    <h1>@q.QuestionRanking. @q.Question1</h1>
</div><div class="form-group">
    @switch (qtype)
    {
        case 1:
            // Textbox
            @Html.TextArea("Answer", q.Answer, new { @class = "form-control",  rows="4", cols="10" })
            break;

        case 2:
            //  Dropdown
            <select class="form-control" id="Answer" name="Answer">
                @foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
                {
                    if (q.Answer == item.QuestionOption1)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.QuestionOption1" selected>@item.QuestionOption1</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@item.QuestionOption1">@item.QuestionOption1</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
                break;
...
    }
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" value="@q.Id" /
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" name="@q.formNumber" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save answer" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
**Html.EndForm();**
}
```

And here is my controller;

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Template.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace Template.Controllers
{
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    private WebTemplateEntities db = new WebTemplateEntities();

    // GET: /Questions/ViewQuestion/5
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int page = 1)
    {
        // If user is not logged in, push them back to Login
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (userId == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        // Get the list of Questions and Response options from the database
        List<GetQuestionViewModel> quest = new List<GetQuestionViewModel>();

        var i = 1; // for form array

        foreach (var item in db.Questions.Where(q => q.PageNumber == page))
        {
            //Check if user has submitted a response
            var reply = db.Responses.Where(r => r.QuestionId == item.Id && r.UserId == userId).Select(r => r.Answer).ToList();
            //If no input, do not look for answers
            if (reply.Count == 0)
            {
                quest.Add(new GetQuestionViewModel()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    QuestionOptions = db.QuestionOptions
                    .Where(k => k.QuestionId == item.Id)
                    .ToList(),
                    PageNumber = item.PageNumber,
                    Question1 = item.Question1,
                    QuestionRanking = item.QuestionRanking,
                    QuestionTypeId = item.QuestionTypeId,
                    formNumber = "form" + i // for form array
                });
            }
            else //If user has input answers find them
            {
                quest.Add(new GetQuestionViewModel()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    QuestionOptions = db.QuestionOptions
                    .Where(k => k.QuestionId == item.Id)
                    .ToList(),
                    PageNumber = item.PageNumber,
                    Question1 = item.Question1,
                    QuestionRanking = item.QuestionRanking,
                    QuestionTypeId = item.QuestionTypeId,
                    formNumber = "form" + i, // for form array
                    Answer = reply.First()
                });
            }        
            i++; // for form array
        }
        return View(quest);
    }

    // POST: /Questions/ViewQuestion/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion([Bind(Include = "QuestionId, Answer, UserId")] ResponseViewModel responseViewModel)
    {
        // Get page and question id
        var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["page"];  //NOTE: Problem with binding on multi form pages
        var qId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["QuestionId"]; //NOTE: Problem with binding on multi form pages
        var newAnswer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Answer"]; 
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(qId);   //NOTE: Problem with binding on multi form pages

        //Check if user has previously answerer
        List<Response> reply = new List<Response>();
        reply = (from r in db.Responses
                    where r.QuestionId == a && r.UserId == responseViewModel.UserId
                    select r ).ToList();

        // If this is the first time the user has answered, add the response
        if (reply.Count() == 0)
        {
            Response re = new Models.Response();
            re.Answer = responseViewModel.Answer;
            re.UserId = responseViewModel.UserId;
            re.QuestionId = responseViewModel.QuestionId;
            re.Source = "Web";
            re.Status = "New";
            re.DateStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
            db.Responses.Add(re);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else // If the user has already answered move the original responses to AuditTrail
        {
            var ans = reply.Select(r => r.Id).First();
            var dos = reply.Select(r => r.Answer).First();
            AuditTrail au = new Models.AuditTrail();
            au.ResponseId = ans;
            au.OriginalData = dos;
            au.DateChanged = System.DateTime.Now;
            db.AuditTrails.Add(au);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Update user's response
            var stat = "Update, 1"; // NOTE: Work in progress; create array of updates to track number of updates
            var updateAnswer = db.Responses.Single(q => q.Id == ans);
            updateAnswer.Answer = newAnswer;
            updateAnswer.Status = stat;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
            return RedirectToAction("ViewQuestion/" + page);
    }
  }
}
```

There are more question type cases but I left them out for clarity.

Where there is more than one question and response per screen the post action returns an array of all the forms on the page. From my initial investigations I cannot see how to determine which specific form is submitted therefore I do not know how to pull the correct response.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

There is concept called **PartialView** in MVC. You can use this to can render multiple forms in single page.

Comment: So I would put the form in the partial view and give each partial view form a unique name? I'm not sure I get how to do this. Can you point me to an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

How utterly stupid I feel!! I didn't close the form!

For those of you struggling with the same issue, simply close with Html.EndForm();

I placed it right after the last line in my view and now it returns only the values from the submitted form.

And my boss spotted it..... Not a good day!